# windows runas netonly with incorrect password

Tags: windows, user-accounts, runas

On Windows 7 I'm using `runas /netonly /user:...` to run something under a different account. If I mistype the password the program starts under my current user.

`runas` doesn't even appear to set the `ERRORLEVEL` when this happens. Is there any way to detect when the user mistyped and failed to log on to the new account? The following doesn't work:

```
runas /netonly /user:my_other_username c:\programs\etc\something.exe
if ERRORLEVEL 1 pause
```

Why does the program start, rather than failing and reporting the bad password? I can't think of any good reason why this should be the default behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `/netonly`, the provided credentials are only applied to *network connections* (SMB, RPC). The process is being run as the same local user. Therefore, `runas` has no way of knowing whether you entered the correct password.

To actually run a program as different account, omit the `/netonly` switch.

Comment: I see, so it's actually running as the local user. I suppose that makes sense. Rubbish. Shame there's no way it could test a network connection with the supplied credentials.

Comment: @Joe: Since it cannot know _what_ network connections you are going to use, no.

Comment: That's a fair point.